# What is the right configuration to deploy a default Notary node in a network?

Tags: corda

I'm deploying a corda network using two different machines: in the first I'm deploying a notary and an oracle service using the following configuration:

**Notary**

```
myLegalName="O=Notary,L=London,C=GB"
keyStorePassword : "cordacadevpass"
trustStorePassword : "trustpass"
p2pAddress="machine-ip1:10004"
notary : {
    validating : false
}
devMode : true
```

**Oracle**

```
myLegalName="O=Oracle,L=London,C=GB"
keyStorePassword : "cordacadevpass"
trustStorePassword : "trustpass"
p2pAddress="machine-ip1:10001"
rpcSettings {
    address="0.0.0.0:10002"
    adminAddress="0.0.0.0:10003"
}
rpcUsers=[
    {
        password=test
        permissions=[
            ALL
        ]
        user=user1
    }
]
devMode : true
```

In the second I'm deploying the following party node:

**Party**

```
myLegalName="O=Party,L=London,C=GB"
keyStorePassword : "cordacadevpass"
trustStorePassword : "trustpass"
p2pAddress="machine-ip2:10001"
rpcSettings {
    address="0.0.0.0:10002"
    adminAddress="0.0.0.0:10003"
}
rpcUsers=[
    {
        password=test
        permissions=[
            ALL
        ]
        user=user1
    }
]
devMode : true
```

Once `Party` starts a flow building a transaction it fails raising this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Need to specify a notary for the state, or set a default one on TransactionBuilder 
        at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.addOutputState(TransactionBuilder.kt:172) 
        at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.addOutputState$default(TransactionBuilder.kt:171)
```

The call function is :

```
override fun call(): SignedTransaction {

    val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.getNotary(CordaX500Name("Notary", "London", "GB"))!!

    val issueState = CashOwningState(amount, ourIdentity)
    val issueCommand = Command(
        CashIssueContract.Commands.Issue(),
        issueState.participants.map { it.owningKey })

    val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary).withItems(
        StateAndContract(issueState, CashIssueContract.TEST_CONTRACT_ID),
        issueCommand)

    txBuilder.verify(serviceHub)

    val fullySignedTx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder)

    return subFlow(FinalityFlow(fullySignedTx, FINALIZING_TX.childProgressTracker()))
}
```

It seems that the `Notary` is found in the network, but the CordApp doesn't recognize it as a notary.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue of the CorDapp not recognising the notary. The only place this exception is thrown is [here](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/transactions/TransactionBuilder.kt#L174):

```
@JvmOverloads
fun addOutputState(state: ContractState, contract: ContractClassName, constraint: AttachmentConstraint = AutomaticHashConstraint): TransactionBuilder {
    checkNotNull(notary) { "Need to specify a notary for the state, or set a default one on TransactionBuilder initialisation" }
    addOutputState(state, contract, notary!!, constraint = constraint)
    return this
}
```

When instantiating a `TransactionBuilder` by passing in a notary, no check is performed for whether the party being passed is in fact a notary.

You must be trying to add an output state to a `TransactionBuilder` without a notary somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I managed to get the notary by bootstrapping the network including the notary configuration file inside the same directory where the other configurations (the oracle and the party ones) where placed. Without so, the network parameters weren't generated correctly, because the notary conf file was missing.

Comment: Then are you sure your code above is correct? The notary is clearly found because you check that `getNotary` doesn't return `null`.